# Getting a JSON Response from the Django

Tags: python, json, django, dropzone.js

EDIT:
As asked, the thing that I'm trying to obtain is the following:

POST with the file from template --> File process in the view, generate an id --> id displays in template

I'm new to Django, and I'm trying to get the server to send a response to the same page, with a certain number. It's currently responding with a ValueError, and the template doesn't get the response. Here is my code.

views.py

```
def index(request):
dB = LegacyDatabase()
ints = None
if request.POST:
    form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        files = Upload(model=request.FILES['file_upload'])
        try:
            ints = dBconnection(dB, request.FILES['file_upload'].name)
        except IntegrityError:
            ints = dBGetExistingValue(dB, request.FILES['file_upload'].name)
        files.save()
        a = []
        a.append(["sessionid", ints])
        sess= dict(a)

        return JsonResponse(sess)
return render(request, "main/index.html")
```

urls.py
    from django.conf.urls import url

```
from phast.views import index

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^$', index, name='main'),
]
```

index.html

```
   <form method="post" class = "sessionid">
    <input type="text" id = "demo" readonly>
  </form>
  <script>

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      console.log(JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText));
      }
    };
  </script>

 <form class="dropzone" id="mydropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data">  {% csrf_token %} </form>
```

dropzone creation

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#mydropzone", {
  url : '{% url phast.views.index %}'
});
```

Can you please help me?

EDIT:
As asked, here is the error that the development server returns.

```
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/rubinhus/Development/django/phastload/phast/views.py", line 66, in index
    return render(request, "main/index.html", JsonResponse(sess))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 30, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 68, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 64, in render
    context = make_context(context, request, autoescape=self.backend.engine.autoescape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/context.py", line 267, in make_context
    context.push(original_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/context.py", line 59, in push
    return ContextDict(self, *dicts, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/context.py", line 18, in __init__
    super(ContextDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 19; 2 is required
```

Comment: If you're getting an error, you should *post it* along with the full traceback.

Comment: However I would be interested to know why you think there will be a field called "file_upload" in the POST data.

Comment: It's the name of the Dropzone that is in the template. My thinking is that the POST data has a reference to the file that was uploaded, if this is not correct can you please explain? Either way the traceback is posted

Comment: What "Dropzone"? That's the first you've mentioned it. Also please notice that the tenth line of the traceback shows that the error is happening in *different* code than what you have posted. We can't possibly help you if you don't show your actual code.

Comment: The webapp is supposed to get a file from a dropzone, upload it to a server, and then the views will process the filename, entering it and an id in the database, and it should return as a json response the id. The error is now correct. Thanks for the input in the question structure, I'm new to this.

Comment: OK but can you explain why you are using this (wrong) code rather than the previous (correct) one?

Comment: I guess I'm trying stuff, the template is not receiving any response. Good to know the first was correct though.

Answer (score 0):

By what I see:

The trace back says in line 66 of views.py:

> return render(request, "main/index.html", JsonResponse(sess))

This is the last line of your code and rest all are inbuilt of django. So you should instead concentrate on this line.

My approach would be to check the 66th line of views.py and debug whats going on there. If you don't see similar code in line 66 of views.py I bet you haven't restarted your django process. How are you running the server? If any process is supervising it restart that process.

### EDIT

[Template Context Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.base.Template.render)

> If context is provided, it must be a dict. If it isn’t provided, the engine will render the template with an empty context.

You were providing a `JsonResponse` to it. It is a repsponse which will contain status code of the request, headers d body as well.

so replacing `return JsonResponse(sess)` with `render(request, "main/index.html", context=sess)` should work.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the code with the feedback from the other comment. It is now correct, but the template is not receiving the response

Comment: I did not understand in what part of your template you are not receiving the response. Maybe you should restructure your question to add more specificity.

Are you trying to acheive below:
**GET request** --> Template --> Display empty form
**POST request**  --> Template --> Display with posted data

Comment: I've edited the post, see if it's clear now, please.

Comment: Then replace `if request.POST` with `if request.method == 'POST'`. Then in the return inside the if loop do instead of `return JsonResponse(sess)` replace with `return render(request, "main/index.html", context=sess)`. Check my edited answer.